SessionNotCreatedException : Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure
My Selenium test suite is running without any problem on my local comp. but in azure pipeline, it is running for some time without any problem,scenarios passing successfuly, than failing at random scenario(mostly third), while navigating the website. After failed, rest of the scenarios failing too and test is rınning 50-60 minutes simetimes even more. normally it should take 10-15 min. Before that, tests used to run without problem on azure. than ı start to get session not started-not quited exceptions and updated to pom dependencies. after that this errors coming. ı tried different scenarios, different profiles on pom, it does not changed the situation. Here is the error log and my project details:
first error:
Given Naviagate to Microfon FAILED 1 m 2.980 s
`io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class StepDefinitions._05_DataTableSteps
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
 at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
 at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
 at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
 at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
 at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:228)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:961)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:201)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
DETAILED SECTION -- 17 --
# Step / Hook Details Status Duration
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:136)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
 ... 50 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid
address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Host info: host: 'fv-az795-342', ip: '10.1.0.8'
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
 at Utilities.GWD.getDriver(GWD.java:87)
 at Pages.Parent.<init>(Parent.java:24)
 at Pages.LeftNav.<init>(LeftNav.java:10)
 at StepDefinitions._05_DataTableSteps.<init>(_05_DataTableSteps.java:30)
 ... 55 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version: '4.18.1',
revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8-internal' Driver
info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:253)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:117)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
 ... 65 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
server to start. Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
'10.0', java.version: '11.0.8-internal' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
DETAILED SECTION -- 18 --
# Step / Hook Details Status Duration
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:234)
 ... 67 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version: '4.18.1',
revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8-internal' Driver
info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:278)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.lambda$start$1(DriverService.java:212)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:15366/status] to be available after
20000 ms
 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:94)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:274)
 ... 5 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:91)

`
After a scenario failed, rest of the scenarios failing too:
Given Naviagate to Microfon FAILED 53.883 s
`io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class StepDefinitions._05_DataTableSteps
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
 at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
 at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
 at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
 at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
 at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
 at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
DETAILED SECTION -- 22 --
# Step / Hook Details Status Duration
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:228)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:961)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:201)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
 at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:136)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
 at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
 ... 50 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid
address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Host info: host: 'fv-az795-342', ip: '10.1.0.8'
DETAILED SECTION -- 23 --
# Step / Hook Details Status Duration
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
 at Utilities.GWD.getDriver(GWD.java:87)
 at Pages.Parent.<init>(Parent.java:24)
 at Pages.LeftNav.<init>(LeftNav.java:10)
 at StepDefinitions._05_DataTableSteps.<init>(_05_DataTableSteps.java:30)
 ... 55 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port. Build info: version:
'4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8-internal'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:249)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:117)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)

here is the detail of my project:
POM.xml  (ı tried almost every possible combinations of dependencies. this is current pom.)
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>microfon-test-automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.18.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.18.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>

                <includes>
                    <!-- for  run class or classes  **/:bulunduğu lokasyonu bütün klasörlere göre bulabiliyor   -->
                    <include>**/TestRunnerSmoke.java</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Smoke</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>

                    <includes>
                        <!-- for  run class or classes  **/:bulunduğu lokasyonu bütün klasörlere göre bulabiliyor   -->
                        <include>**/TestRunnerSmoke.java</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</profile>

    </project>

My Driver Settings:
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("EN"));
        System.setProperty("user.language", "EN");

        if (driver == null) {

            Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            System.setProperty(org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY, "Error");
            System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearResolutionCache();
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache();
          // WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();  (normally ı use this)
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("127.0.6533.100").setup();

            if (!runningFromIntelliJ()) {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1400,2400");
//               options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
//                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

//                        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            } else {
//                               ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//                        options.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080");
//                        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
//                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
//                driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // bu threade bir webdriver atanıyor
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static boolean runningFromIntelliJ() {
        String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        return classPath.contains("idea_rt.jar");
    }

    public static void quitDriver() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if (driver != null)  // dolu ise
        {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }
    }

My Hooks
public class Hooks {
    @Before
    public void before(Scenario senaryo) {
        System.out.println("Senaryo başladı: "+senaryo.getName());
    }

    @After
    public void after(Scenario senaryo) {
        System.out.println("Senaryo bitti Status:"+senaryo.getStatus());

            if (senaryo.isFailed())
            {
                final byte[] byteHali = ((TakesScreenshot) GWD.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                senaryo.attach(byteHali, "image/png", "screenshot name");
            }
            GWD.quitDriver();
     }
}

My runner class:
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = "@SmokeTest",
        features = {"src/test/java/FeatureFiles"},
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"}
//     , plugin= {"pretty","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json"}
     , plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
)
public class TestRunnerSmoke extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @AfterClass
    public void writeExtentReport() {
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("Windows User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("User Name", "");
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("Application Name", "");
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("Operating System Info", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        ExtentService.getInstance().setSystemInfo("Department", "QA");
    }
}


there's an if/else there for running from IDE, but you set the same path in either condition.  That path should be absolute and get rid of the if/else logic.  i.e.: "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe"  Use absolute path there.  Also, you probably shouldn't be using WebDriverManager, as it's built-in to Selenium now.  (not sure that'll work anymore unless you use Java V8.. and it looks like you've got 11.x there)
